# Plot Confusion matrix for all the samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

Hi I am trying to plot a confusion matrix for all the samples that I am using for testing. However, since I have specified batc_size the confusion matrix outputs all the correct classes only for the specified number of batch_size. ie., If I have an overall 3000 samples instead of predicting for all the 3000 samples confusion matrix predicts only for the 150 samples if the batch size is specified as 150. Could you please help to find out what I can do differently to plot the confusion matrix for all 3000 samples.

```
    num_classes = 2
    image_resize = 256
    train_dir ='./..../..'#3000 samples
    test_dir = './.../...'#3000 samples
    batch_size_training = 150
    batch_size_validation = 150
    num_epochs = 10
    
    data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,validation_split=0.2)
    
    
    train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(image_resize, image_resize),
        batch_size=batch_size_training,
        class_mode='categorical')
    validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(image_resize, image_resize),
        batch_size=batch_size_validation,
        class_mode='categorical')
    test_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        test_dir,
        target_size=(image_resize, image_resize),
        batch_size=batch_size_validation,
        class_mode='categorical')
    
    x_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
    x_val,y_val = next(validation_generator)
    x_test, y_test = next(test_generator)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])


steps_per_epoch_training = int(np.floor(train_generator.n // batch_size_training ))

steps_per_epoch_validation = int(np.floor(validation_generator.n // batch_size_validation ))


fit_history = model.fit(train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_training,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_validation,
    verbose=1,
)
    
probs = model.predict(x_test)
preds = probs.argmax(axis = -1)
accuracy = 100*(np.mean(preds == y_test.argmax(axis=-1)))
y_test = np.argmax(y_test,axis=-1)
        
print("Classification accuracy: %f " % (accuracy))
cm =confusion_matrix(y_test,preds)
print(cm)
df_cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, range(2), range(2))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sn.set(font_scale=1.4) # for label size
sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 16}) # font size
fig.savefig('CM.jpg')
```

Comment: What is the shape of x_test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have literally picked up just a single batch from your data generators:

```py
...
x_train, y_train = next(train_generator)
x_val,y_val = next(validation_generator)
x_test, y_test = next(test_generator)
...
```

And then you used that single test batch to run predictions on it:

```py
...
probs = model.predict(x_test)
...
```

So the code runs exactly as expected running predictions on a single batch.

To run predictions on all the test data from your generator you should be able to simply do this:

```
# to get predictions for all test data points
probs = model.predict(test_generator)
# to get labels for all the test data points
y_test = test_generator.labels
```